# PowerShell Attempted to perform an unauthorised operation

Tags: powershell, taxonomy, multi-tenancy

I'm trying to add a term store administrator using PowerShell.  I'm logged on to one of the farm web servers with a farm administrator account (also happens to be a domain admin account too).  I'm running the following PowerShell:

```
$ts = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site https://test.splab.local
$termStore = $ts.TermStores["Tenant Taxonomy Proxy"]
$termStore.AddTermStoreAdministrator("splab\user1")
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> Exception calling "AddTermStoreAdministrator" with "1" argument(s):
>   "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation"

I'm guessing this is some sort of permissions problem but no idea what.

Supplementary details:
- SharePoint 2010 on top of Windows 2008
- Configured the web app to be multi-tenanted
- Using Claims Based Authentication with a custom claims provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the account you're using have Term Store Administrator rights in the farm? You may want to take a look at this blog post and see if your account is set up in the areas it mentions: http://jyothiregode.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/create-termset-programmatically-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010/

John